# Quickest way to calculate the euclidean distance matrix of two list of points

Tags: python, numpy

Using python and numpy I have the following problem. I have two lists of 2D points which are actually `Mx2` and `Nx2` sized matrices (let's call `A` and `B` respectively). What I intend to reach is a `MxN` sized matrix where the `(i,j)`. th entry is the Euclidean distance between the points `A[i,:]` and `B[j,:]`. Simply doing a matrix multiplication `np.dot(A,np.tranpose(B))` will just give me the dot products between the points so this does not work for me. Since `M` and `N` in the scale of tens of thousands, using for loops are prohibitively slow for me. We have `numpy.apply_along_axis`but as far as I know this is not much different than a for loop under the hood. So, what would be the most fast way to do that?

Comment: [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)

Comment: see [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

Comment: I think scipy.spatial.distance_matrix solves my question